# Html.HiddenFor outputs two different values on same view

Tags: model-view-controller, html-helper

I frequently output hidden elements onto my views using the HiddenFor Html Helper like so:

```
      <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SourceType) %>
```

On one view, and I can't figure out why, I noticed the Value="" for the type input was blank like this:

```
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="" name="SourceType">
```

In troubleshooting I simply output the value using TextBoxFor like so and got the desired value.

```
      <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SourceType) %>
```

This is where things get a little strange. I was reading posts and trying different markups. I ended up with this markup to see what would happen:

```
      <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SourceType) %>
      <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SourceType) %>
```

The resulting html is this:

```
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="" name="SourceType">
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="0" name="SourceType">
```

This seems strange. How could two identical hiddenfor helpers, in a Get request, on the same view, and using the same Model result in two different values?

EDIT:

I thought it could be the first element is always blank so I added TextBoxFor before both hidden elements like this:

```
      <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SourceType) %>
      <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SourceType) %>
      <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SourceType) %>
```

This results in:

```
      <input id="SourceType" type="text" value="0" name="SourceType">
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="0" name="SourceType">
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="0" name="SourceType">
```

Now all three are correct. It appears only the first HiddenFor is blank when it is output first. If the value is referenced by something other than a HiddenFor it works. Huh?

I just made sure none of my scripts are affecting the value by removing them from the page. First Hidden is still blank...

So to summarize:

1. The value is blank for a hidden for helper
2. When the hidden for is the first helper to touch the model property
3. When the model property is referenced/ output before the hidden for helper using <% Model.Type %> and/ or <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Type) %> the value in subsequent hidden inputs is output correctly by the hidden for helper.

This must mean that something is happening to the Model or ModelState when the property is referenced. What could the HiddenFor helper be looking for that it doesn't find until after something else touches the property?

Comment: If you print the value `model.Type` directly (e.g. `<%:model.Type%>`), what value do you get? You have the same odd behavior?

Comment: No, it works as expected with <%: Model.Type %>. The output is 0. I also noticed something else. See edits above.

Comment: This has something to do with the name of the property. I updated my question with the name I am actually using which is SourceType. To confirm the helper doesn't like SourceType as a property name I changed the name of the proper to Foo in my view model and the behavior stopped. The problem is I don't have the luxury of using a different property name and SourceType seems to work in a large number of other views... what could cause this view to care about the name?

Comment: You are checking the value of the hidden input by viewing the HTML or through developer tools? If the later, it could be a JavaScript code that could alter this

Comment: BINGO! I thought I had removed all the scripts, but I must have missed something somewhere. I just removed every script from the page the value is correct. Thanks Tasos K! Your comment got me to dig a little deeper. Probably saved me hours.

Comment: OPPS! Looks like I was premature or just hopeful. I've removed all scripts... still the same strange behavior. I even removed the Jquery Library itself.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I tried to reproduce the issue but without success (C#, .NET 4.0)

Comment: Haven't figured it out... Looking at it again today. I've removed all javascript but the value still looks like value=""

Comment: Found a work around. I did this <input id="SourceType" type="text" value="<%: Model.SourceType %>" style="visibility: hidden;"/> and the value was placed correctly and the element is not rendered on the page. Anyone know why an input element with type="hidden" would behave this way?